# Reconhecer erro provider (Node.js, TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, typescript

Estou tendo um problema de envio de uma requisição, que sai do meu arquivo TypeScript, eu envio para o insomnia e gera o erro apenas após o envio.

Arquivo TypeScript :

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';

const appointmentsRouter = Router();

const appointments = [];

appointmentsRouter.post('/',(request, response) =>{
  const { provider, date } = request.body;
  const appointment = {
    id: uuid(),
    provider,
    date,
  };

  appointments.push(appointment);
  return response.json(appointment)
});

export default appointmentsRouter;
```

Requisição do insomnia:

```
{
    "provider" : "Diego Fernandes",
    "date" : "{% now 'iso-8601', '' %}"
}
```

Erro gerado após o envio:

> insira o TypeError: Cannot read property 'provider' of undefined
> at /home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/src/routes/appointments.routes.ts:9:19
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at /home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
> at next (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
> at Function.handle (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
> at router (/home/decco/projetos/projetoNode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
> aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oi, tive o mesmo erro, adicionei a linha `app.use(express.json());` no arquivo server. Ficou assim:

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);

app.listen(3333, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3333!');
});
```